# How to edit the text created by Yeoman in hyperledger composer?

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular, hyperledger-composer

```
asset Vehicle identified by vin{
o String vin
o String vehicleMake
}
```

In above example, `yo hyperledger-composer` generates Angular skeleton which uses the asset variables as table headings and form labels as it is i.e. 'vin' and 'vehicleMake' in angular web app. How can this be changed to 'Vehicle Number' and 'Vehicle Make' in angular web app?

I tried changing directly in the Vehicle.component.html and it worked. But when the command is run again, all the changes done directly are overridden. Space cannot be added in code itself, as it gives syntax issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Angular generator doesn't support any round-trip code generation (preserving user edits), so you either need to stabilise your model and then run the generator once (manually making any changes thereafter) or diff the output from the generator and manually apply the changes to your modified code base.

Comment: So, basically the scope of Composer towards web app is to provide REST services. Once the services are created they can be used in 'yo hyperledger-composer' skeleton or can be directly used in a separate angular application.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Correct. The skeletal Angular app generated by the Composer yo generator uses the composer-rest-server to interact with the blockchain. It is provided as a useful starting point for development. We'd love to see more templates for other frameworks developed by the community (React.js, Vue.js etc).